# Making a dependency optional in my package used by create-react-app, Vite, and others

Tags: create-react-app, es6-modules

We have an npm package `@glowbuzzer/controls`. This package can make use of STEP file import functionality from `occt-import-js`, but not all users of `@glowbuzzer/controls` are interested in STEP files and may not want to add `occt-import-js` to their `package.json` (and shouldn't need to).

I am attempting to handle this by doing a dynamic import:

```
  try {
    const occtLib = import("occt-import-js");
    occtLib.then((occt) => {
      // do something with lib
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error loading occt-import-js", err);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn("No occt-import-js found. STEP files will not be supported");
  }
```

However, when using `@glowbuzzer/controls` in a CRA app, we get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'occt-import-js'
```

Project will not run without installing `occt-import-js`. Is there any way around this error if dependency is not present?

Comment: Is it OK to separate the STEP import function to another package, like `@glowbuzzer/step-import`? That way, you can completely remove `occt-import-js` dependency from `@glowbuzzer/controls`.

Comment: Yes thanks I considered this and it would work, but it seems like overkill for 50 lines of code! And I'm interested in the dynamic/optional import problem in general. Am sure there are other libs that manage to do this.

Comment: "*when using [the module] in a CRA app, we get the following error*" - where exactly are you getting that error? From which tool? Is it an exception in the running code, a console warning about a module that couldn't be loaded, a bundler error that it couldn't find/resolve the module, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch static imports errors

Yet, you could use a dynamic import() for that.

It is supported by most browsers & Node and CRA(Tested it out)

```js
const loadModule = async (modulePath) => {
  try {
    return await import(modulePath)
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn("No occt-import-js found. STEP files will not be supported");
  }
}

loadModule('occt-import-js');
```

Comment: "*you could use a dynamic `import()` for that.*" - isn't that exactly what the OP has tried, but claims not to work?

Comment: Yeah but I added an await and also I tried this approach and it worked in a CRA

Comment: Ah, also you didn't hardcode the `modulePath` right in the `import()` expression, may that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, seems that was the main difference